# Rounding Up Numbers in Number Range

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-cleaning

I am trying to figure out how to handle variations in number ranges I'm receiving.  I've compiled them from a dataframe and am trying to get all the ranges in a 100-200 / 200-300 / 300-400 format.

Sometimes they'll be entered as 300.400 instead of 300-400 and sometimes they'll be entered as 300.5-400.5.  If possible, I'd also like to account for a situation where they are entered as 300.5.400.5 because as insane as it is, someone might do it.  I guess I should probably try to plan for any character that isn't "-" showing up between them.

To boil it down, I want to round up numbers with decimals and replace non "-" characters separating ranges without replacing periods in decimals.

Excuse my terrible code:

```
num_range = [p.replace(' ', '') for p in num_dirty]
num_range = [p.replace(';', ' ') for p in num_dirty]
num_range = [p.replace('.', '-') for p in num_dirty]

num_clean = []

for r in num_dirty:
    num_clean.append(r.split('/'))

num_clean = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(num_clean))

num_clean = ','.join(num_clean)
```

I'm also using this function I found on here to list out all of the numbers in the frequency range so that I can remove any duplicate ranges:

```
num_lines = num_clean.split(',')
num_numbers = []
i = 0
for line in num_lines:
    if line == '':
        continue
    elif '-' in line:
        t = line.split('-')
        num_numbers += range(int(t[0]), int(t[1]) + 1)
    else:
        num_numbers.append(int(line))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following regex on the first two paragraphs of your post

```
import re
from math import ceil

pat = re.compile(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
l = [(ceil(float(a)), ceil(float(b))) for a, b in pat.findall(your_post)]
print(l)
# [(100, 200), (200, 300), (300, 400), (300, 400), (300, 400), (301, 401), (301, 401)]
```

From there you can produce formatted strings however you want

```
for pair in l:
    print("{}-{}".format(*pair))
```

Comment: After messing around with this, it seems like the answer to my problem.  Thank you!